# How to add active class in wordpress submenu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wp-nav-menu-item

I have a list of `sub-menus` in the page which will get the title of each article.
But I hope the list style will be different from others when it is in the specific article page.

Now the `<a>` tag has only a class named "list-group-item", and I hope there will be another "active" class added in the `<a>` tag when it is in the article.

Hope someone could help me to solve this...thank you in advance.

Here is my codes:

```
<div class="list-group">
 <?php global $post;
   global $all_post_titles;
   $all_post_titles = array();
   $args = array('post_type' => 'service','orderby' => 'ID','order' => 'ASC',);
   $myposts = get_posts( $args );
     foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php the_title();?> <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_the_ID()` to get the ID of the current post page you're visiting and add an additional class `active-item` if it matches the post ID you're querying in the `foreach` loop:

```
 <?php 
 // get the ID of the current post
 $current_id = get_the_ID(); 
 ?>
 <?php foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-group-item<?php echo ($post->ID==$current_id?' active-item':''); ?>"><?php the_title();?> <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php the_title();?>
```

in condition for current article title and add active class like this :

```
<?php 
     $activeclass="";
     if(the_title()== $post->name)
     { 
         $activeclass="active";
     }
 ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-group-item "><?php the_title();?> <span class="fa fa-angle-right <?php echo $activeclass; ?>"></span></a>
```